# Using Selenium Webdriver (with Java) to test a video without ID

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, video, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test a video (its in webm format) that doesn't have ID using standard actions like pause/play/play from beginning. Here is what I found so far http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/road-to-automate-html5-video-with.html

So just paste here part of code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

 //play video
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"video\").play()");
 Thread.sleep(5000);

 //pause playing video 
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"video\").pause()");

 //check video is paused
 System.out.println(js .executeScript("document.getElementById(\"video\").paused"));
```

Unfortunately I can't use this method as video doesn't have ID. I tried to do similar using `document.getElementsByTagName`, but it didn't work (go error `document.getElementsByTagName(...).play` is not a function). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use javascript executor to find the `video` element.

Find it with `selenium` and pass to the executor to control it.

For example, if you were to find it just *by tag name*:

```
WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.tagName("video"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].play();", video);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look for the HTML `video` tag for the Class Name. Then you can use the function `getElementsByClassName()`. This worked for me:

```
(JavascriptExecutor(driver))
    .executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('Video Class Name')[0].click();");
```